# How to properly send udp package in c# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, udp

I am trying to send a string over to another device in my local network using UDP in c#. For a GUI I am using windows forms. I have a button in my GUI that, when pressed, calls the following method:

```
        private void Send_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.15");

            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 5000);

            string text = "Sample text";
            byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

            sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);


        }
```

However, when I run the program and press the button, without getting any error, the GUI window loses focus and the only way for it to regain focus is to press the "Continue" button in Visual Studio Community  2019. Not only that, but the udp packet doesn't get sent at all. What am I doing wrong? 
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have a breakpoint somewhere in this function.

Comment: `sock.Close();`. It's synchronous, so it returns only when the packet is sent. Add a Try/Catch block. With a bad network configuration, it may go to DNS to find the route.

Comment: "the only way for it to regain focus is to press the "Continue" button in Visual Studio Community 2019", what's that? Can you show a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use the BackgroundWorker class to send the data.

The UI won't freeze and the message will be sent in the background.

Just add the BackgroundWorker from the toolbox

For your case, it would be something like this:

```
private void Send_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    IPAddress serverAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.15");
    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverAddr, 5000);
    string text = "Sample text";
    byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

    sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);
}
```

Your Designer class would have something like this:

```
this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
```

If you would like a notification or something, you can just at a handler to the RunWorkerCompleted event.